# Angular 4 (or plain javascript) solution to block user input while dialog is shown?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a security sensitive (payments) app in Angular 4.
The system has a timeout condition for inactivity. When the timeout is reached a dialog is supposed to pop up telling the user she needs to re-login due to inactivity.

While the dialog is shown the user could potentially right-click to open a context menu and navigate away from the dialog. The same is true for key inputs.

I have therefore disabled both like this (only while dialog shows):

```
window.oncontextmenu = function() { return false };
window.onkeydown = function() { return false };
```

That works fine and prevents any navigation while dialog shows.

However, there is one work-around I'd like to prevent:
If you open a context menu before the timeout dialog pops up that context menu remains active while the dialog is active and allows the user to navigate away (choosing back or reload).

Is there a way to close an open context menu in my dialog component?
Or any other way to prevent that scenario (short of from preventing context menus altogether)?
Obviously, I cannot disable mouse events, otherwise the user could never activate the button on the timeout dialog.

Comment: What about opening your dialog as a new page. One trick to control user input is to cover the whole page with a transparent div but im not sure if that is going to help you in this case

Comment: Are you using an auth guard on your routes? Even if the context menu edge case wasn't an issue the user could still click the back button in the browser. I would add an auth guard to each route that checks if the user is authenticated. Then whenever the user navigates forward, backward, or reloads the auth guard is ran and if they arent authenticated it kicks them back to the login page.

Comment: Initiate the close event of Context menu at the time of Popup initialization.

Comment: @The Dictator: sure, but I don't know how. Pls post a code sample.

Comment: @hholtij Can you please post the code that you have done ?

Comment: No, it's too much. Just show me how to close an open context menu and I can figure out the rest.

Comment: @LLai: I do have auth guards on all routes. However, by the time the timeout dialog pops up the user is still logged in. We are using identity server 4 for authentication which uses callbacks, which always result in a reboot of the app. In other words, if I log the user out first, the app reboots and the timeout dialog would never show and the user would not know what's going on.

Comment: @hholtij Does the client make a request to identity server 4 to log the user out? or do you have an open connection (or poll) the auth server to determine when the user gets logged out? do you have control over the app rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2+, you can capture any event like:

```
<div (anyEventName)="whateverEventHandler($event)">
</div>
```

Note that $event is optional, and the return of the function is the return of the event handler, so, you can return false; to avoid default browser action from the event.

In your case the event name is contextmenu. So, your code can be something like this:

## app.component.html:

```
<div (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)">
      Right clicked
      {{nRightClicks}}
      time(s).
    </div>
```

#### app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)">
      Right clicked
      {{nRightClicks}}
      time(s).
    </div>
  `,
  // Just to make things obvious in browser
  styles: [`
    div {
      background: green;
      color: white;
      white-space: pre;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  `]
})
export class App {
  nRightClicks = 0;

  constructor() {
  }

  onRightClick() {
    this.nRightClicks++;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's a full working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7c7nvf

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Devansh. However, I said in my question that I'd like to avoid having to disable the context menu altogether, which is what your solution does.